# Page layout changes on zoom in

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on page layout, still pretty new to it. The page contains various panels of different sizes. A common panel content looks like that:

```
<div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-6">
        <strong>Some metadata name</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-6">
        <strong>Some value</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-6">
        <strong>Some metadata name</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-6">
        <strong>Some value</strong>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Now I'm working on responsiveness: When using the browser zoom-in function, if those title/value pairs don't have enough space to stay beneath each other, I'd like them reflow below each other:
From

```
Title1    Value1
Title2    Value2
Title3    Value3
```

to

```
Title1
Value1
Title2
Value2
Title3
Value3
```

This works by using

```
.ui-g {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ui-g-6 {
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now my problem is the following:
For some panel like

```
Title    Value Value Value Value Value Value Value Value Value Value
```

, when scrolling in, I first get

```
Title    Value Value Value Value Value
         Value Value Value Value Value
```

and then

```
Title    
Value Value Value Value Value
Value Value Value Value Value
```

even though I was expecting

```
Title    
Value Value Value Value Value Value Value Value Value Value
```

as long as this line has enough space.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Please share your code through, code snippet

Comment: Hi:) It's not a good idea to change the layout on 'browser zoom-in function'. Perhaps you mean to change the layout on lower resolutions?

Comment: @Azu I'm working on a government project that includes tests to guarantee okay experiences for visually impaired, and the Ctrl+Scroll zoom is one test case. But yeah, I guess lower resolutions would be an equivalent case, sure.

Comment: @Katheer what code is missing? I already added my CSS.